# Cover code from promise with unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have some logic inside my promise. Is it possible to cover this logic with unit tests? For example, I fire google analytics event inside this promise in my controller and want to make something like `expect($analytics.eventTrack).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)`.

Comment: You might want to give some more details and code. Where is this promise created and how is it called?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the way to cover the code which is inside the promise can be the following: 
let's suppose that on saving some data we fire a GA event inside our promise which says that the data was saved.
We have a service `VoteService` which has a method `saveVote`. This method makes a request to the server and returns a promise. Inside our promise, we fire GA event (when save was successfully executed).
To write the test for this we need in `beforeEach`:

1. create a promise `saveVoteDeferrer = $q.defer();`
2. resolve the promise with needed data
3. spyOn service's method

   `spyOn(VoteServiceMock,'saveVote')
   .and.returnValue(saveVoteDeferrer.promise);`

And then in `it`:

1. Call controller's method which contains service's method:

   `$ctrl.addVote();`
2. verify if the GA event was fired inside our promise body 
   `expect($analytics.eventTrack)
   .toHaveBeenCalledWith('NewVoteAdded', {});`

Bellow the sample:

**voteController.js**

```
var vm = this;
vm.addVote = function(){
//some logic goes here
VoteService.saveVote(vote)
  .then(function(result){
    //some logic goes here
    $analytics.eventTrack('NewVoteAdded', {});
  });
}
```

**VoteService.js**

```
return function(){
  this.saveVote = function($http){
    // some logic goes here
    return $http.post(/*needed parameters*/);
  }
}
```

**vote.spec.js**

```
describe('some text', function(){
 beforeEach(function () { 
  // inject what you need
  // mock VoteService service 
  // inject voteController controller
  var saveVoteDeferrer = $q.defer();
  spyOn($analytics,'eventTrack');
  saveVoteDeferrer.resolve({ data: { } });
  spyOn(VoteServiceMock,'saveVote')
     .and.returnValue(saveVoteDeferrer.promise); 

  it('fire GA event when the vote is saved', function(){
    $ctrl.addVote();
    expect($analytics.eventTrack)
       .toHaveBeenCalledWith('NewVoteAdded', {});  });
  });
});
```